# Razer Anansi doesn't work in GNU GRUB 2

Tags: linux, boot, grub, razer-keyboard

My new Razer Anansi keyboard does not function in the GNU GRUB  version 2.00-19ubuntu2 bootloader that's running on my machine. The backlights do not turn on, and the keyboard is unresponsive.

This makes it rather difficult to select an OS to boot, to put it lightly.

I've currently got both my new Razer keyboard and my old Dynex keyboard plugged in, so that I can load an OS when I restart my computer, but this is not a setup I want to have indefinitely.

What can I do to get my Razer keyboard working at boot?